# Unable to find pip 2.7

Tags: openstack

```
[ERROR] /home/a3/devstack/inc/python:37 Unable to find pip2.7; cannot continue
++./stack.sh:main:724                       err_trap
++./stack.sh:err_trap:510                   local r=1
++./stack.sh:err_trap:511                   set +o xtrace
stack.sh failed
Error on exit
./stack.sh: line 494: generate-subunit: command not found
```

Comment: I would have asked this in https://ask.openstack.org   See https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/60079/devstack-stacksh-failed-unable-to-find-pip/ for a reference. Simple question: did you install pip?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Rinzwind's comment: [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) is a manager for python packages. You need the python 2.7 version of pip, which can be installed like this

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Take a look at [the pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip) for installation details and alternative installation options.

I would recommend using a distribution like [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to manage your python installation. This can be installed in your home folder and does not need administrator right. Also you can easily change python and pip versions if you decide to use another python version.